# Unsubscribe from Redux store when condition is true?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm employing [the suggestion from @gaearon](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409) to setup a listener on my redux store. I'm using this format:

```
function observeStore(store, select, onChange) {
  let currentState;

  if (!Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(select)) {
    select = (state) => state;
  }

  function handleChange() {
    let nextState = select(store.getState());
    if (nextState !== currentState) {
      currentState = nextState;
      onChange(currentState);
    }
  }

  let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);
  handleChange();
  return unsubscribe;
}
```

I'm using this in an `onEnter` handler for a `react-router` route:

```
Entity.onEnter = function makeFetchEntity(store) {
  return function fetchEntity(nextState, replace, callback) {
    const disposeRouteHandler = observeStore(store, null, (state) => {
      const conditions = [
        isLoaded(state.thing1),
        isLoaded(state.thing2),
        isLoaded(state.thing3),
      ];

      if (conditions.every((test) => !!test) {
        callback(); // allow react-router to complete routing
        // I'm done: how do I dispose the store subscription???
      }
    });

    store.dispatch(
      entities.getOrCreate({
        entitiesState: store.getState().entities,
        nextState,
      })
    );
  };
};
```

Basically this helps gate the progression of the router while actions are finishing dispatching (async).

My problem is that I can't figure out where to call `disposeRouteHandler()`. If I call it right after the definition, my `onChange` function never gets a chance to do it's thing, and I can't put it inside the `onChange` function because it's not defined yet.

Appears to me to be a chicken-egg problem. Would really appreciate any help/guidance/insight.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Entity.onEnter = function makeFetchEntity(store) {
  return function fetchEntity(nextState, replace, callback) {
    let shouldDispose = false;
    const disposeRouteHandler = observeStore(store, null, (state) => {
      const conditions = [
        isLoaded(state.thing1),
        isLoaded(state.thing2),
        isLoaded(state.thing3),
      ];

      if (conditions.every((test) => !!test) {
        callback(); // allow react-router to complete routing
        if (disposeRouteHandler) {
          disposeRouteHandler();
        } else {
          shouldDispose = true;
        }
      }
    });
    if (shouldDispose) {
      disposeRouteHandler();
    }

    store.dispatch(
      entities.getOrCreate({
        entitiesState: store.getState().entities,
        nextState,
      })
    );
  };
};
```

Even though using the `observable` pattern leads to some buy-in, you can work around any difficulties with normal js code. Alternatively you can modify your observable to suit your needs better.
For instance:

```
function observeStore(store, select, onChange) {
  let currentState, unsubscribe;

  if (!Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(select)) {
    select = (state) => state;
  }

  function handleChange() {
    let nextState = select(store.getState());
    if (nextState !== currentState) {
      currentState = nextState;
      onChange(currentState, unsubscribe);
    }
  }

  unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);
  handleChange();
  return unsubscribe;
}
```

and

```
Entity.onEnter = function makeFetchEntity(store) {
  return function fetchEntity(nextState, replace, callback) {
    const disposeRouteHandler = observeStore(store, null, (state, disposeRouteHandler) => {
      const conditions = [
        isLoaded(state.thing1),
        isLoaded(state.thing2),
        isLoaded(state.thing3),
      ];

      if (conditions.every((test) => !!test) {
        callback(); // allow react-router to complete routing
        disposeRouteHandler();
      }
    }

    store.dispatch(
      entities.getOrCreate({
        entitiesState: store.getState().entities,
        nextState,
      })
    );
  };
};
```

It does add a strange argument to `onChange`  but it's just one of many ways to do it.

The core problem is that `handleChange` gets called synchronously immediately when nothing has changed yet and asynchronously later. It's known as [Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony).

Comment: You could pass `unsubscribe` to `onChange` as an argument, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer; I used your idea in [another approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103929/32154) I feel might be a bit cleaner: mind sharing your thoughts? I'm also going to go read-up on Zalgo--thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the suggestion from [@DDS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089915/32154), I came up with the following alteration to the other pattern mentioned in [@gaearon's comment](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409):

```
export function toObservable(store) {
  return {
    subscribe({ onNext }) {
      let dispose = this.dispose = store.subscribe(() => {
        onNext.bind(this)(store.getState())
      });

      onNext.bind(this)(store.getState());

      return { dispose };
    },

    dispose: function() {},
  }
}
```

This allows me to invoke like:

```
Entity.onEnter = function makeFetchEntity(store) {
  return function fetchEntity(nextState, replace, callback) {
    toObservable(store).subscribe({
      onNext: function onNext(state) {
        const conditions = [/* many conditions */];

        if (conditions.every((test) => !!test) {
          callback(); // allow react-router to complete routing
          this.dispose(); // remove the store subscription
        }
      },
    });

    store.dispatch(/* action */);
  };
};
```

The key difference is that I'm passing a regular function in for onNext so as not to interfere with my `bind(this)` in `toObservable`; I couldn't figure out how to force the binding to use the context I wanted.

This solution [avoids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089915/32154)

> add[ing] a strange argument to `onChange`

... and in my opinion also conveys a bit more intent: `this.dispose()` is called from within `onNext`, so it kinda reads like `onNext.dispose()`, which is exactly what I want to do.